# searching with multiple parameters with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

How is fine-grained search achiveable with mongodb, without the use of external engines? Take this object as example
    {
      genre:      'comedy',
      pages:      380,
      year:       2013,
      bestseller: true,
      author:     'John Doe'
    }

That is being searched by the following:

```
db.books.find({
  pages:      { '&gt': 100 },
  year:       { '&gt': 2000 },
  bestseller: true,
  author:     "John Doe"
});
```

Pretty straightforward so far. Now suppose that there are a bit more values in the document, and that I am making more refined searches **and** I have a pretty **big** collection.

First thing I would do is to create indexes. But, how does it work? I have read that the index intersection, as defined in here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071 is not doable. That means that if I set the index to "year" and "pages" I will not really optimize the AND operations in searches.

So how can the searches be optimized for having many parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about [compound indexes in mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes).  Compound indexes allow you to create a single index on multiple fields in a document.  By creating compound indexes you can make these large/complex queries while still using an index.

On a more general note, if you create a basic index on a field that is highly selective, your search can end up being very quick.  Using your example, if you had an index on author, the query engine would use that index to find all the entries where author == "John Doe".  Presumably there are not that many books with that specific author relative to the number of books in the entire collection. So, even if the rest of your query is fairly complex, it is only evaluated over those few documents with the matching author.  Thus, by structuring your indexes properly you can get a significant performance gain without having to have any complex indexes.

Comment: Thank you. The code I provided was just an example, though. Do you know if there are any tools that can help looking at frequent queries that can help finding the best matches to create indexes?

Comment: Hi John, I don't know of any tools personally, seems like most people figure it out manually by using the profiler to find which queries run slowly and then optimizing their indexes for those specific queries.